# jQuery Mobile - Margin CSS troubles in buttons

Tags: jquery-mobile, margins

Good afternoon ...
My problem is this ([link to issue image](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-kGkqKcwUxto/VN-exvh2ZiI/AAAAAAAAAAk/pMU5Uaw4us4/w239-h396-no/JQUERY%2BMOBILE%2BISSUE.png)).
When using, for example, a COLLAPSIBLE control, this adds me a higher or lower margin.
I see no statement on the same CSS to display as well.
The code is nothing strange.
Appears well in the pages of demonstrations or others pages. This happens to me on multiple browsers including Chrome and Firefox only with my page.

Thanks for your help and sorry my English.

jQueryMobile version 1.4.5.min
jQuery version 1.11.2.min

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Documento sin título</title>
</head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>


</head>


<body>



<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="b">

<div data-role="header">
<h1>Definición de Formulario</h1>
<input type="text" placeholder="Nombre del formulario" value="" id="nombremapa" name="nombre" />
</div><!-- HEADER -->

<div data-role="content" data-position="fixed" id="campos">
  


</div><!-- CONTENT -->

<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        <div data-role="navbar" >
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#popupMenuAgregar" data-icon="plus" href="#popupMenu" data-rel="popup" data-transition="slideup">Agregar</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-icon="minus">Quitar</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-icon="edit">Editar</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-icon="info">Información</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-icon="mail">Enviar</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

<div data-role="popup" id="popupMenuAgregar" data-theme="b">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" style="min-width:210px;">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Choose an action</li>
            <li><a id="add_texto">Texto</a></li>
            <li><a id="add_numero">Numero</a></li>
            <li><a id="add_fecha">Fecha</a></li>
            <li><a id="add_lista">Lista</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>

</div><!-- FOOTER -->


</div><!-- PAGE -->


</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zwLvjrc2/

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page? Or add some css? Did you checked out the computed style over the developer tools of one of this browsers? There is a style on your page which applyes to this construct which ads the margen. Did mean with "higher or lower margin" that it adds a margin to top or bottem or both?

Comment: Thanks for you quickly response... I dont have a link to the page because is in a corporate intranet. But I add the complete code to my question. I try with a clean code but happend too... edit the publication to see this.

Comment: You could create a fiddle for example which demonstrats your problem in a traceable way. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: You have no custom css at all? Advice look up the css of a working example page and try the same. I'm not that jquery html stuff expert, only reviewing your post to get you started.

Comment: here is de JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zwLvjrc2/ Im only use the jQuery-Mobile css options. I try to modify the CSS to fix this widthout results.

Comment: WOW! The error is in the TAB before <li> tag!!!... Clean this, the render is ok!. May be a invisible space... Thanks!.